# Verifone VX 820 Customization

Tags: small-business

I have a Verifone VX 520 and  VX 820. I saw the VX 820 at another place and theirs was customized with their logo and company name. How can I do that?

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I will try anyways. Please do direct me to the proper site to ask if this is not where I should ask it.

Comment: Please consult [your card's reader documentation](http://support.verifone.com/fstore/0a463145bbfccb42_7ca4a207_135ffd7b912_-53c7/VX_520_Reference_Guide.pdf) or vendor. This question is offtopic here..

Comment: That is for the VX 520 terminal. I cannot find any helpful information in it for the VX 820 credit card machine. That is what I need to know, how to customize the display of the VX 820 credit card machine. Do you know where I could ask? A Google search doesn't help me too much.

Comment: You should consult [Verifon Support](http://www.verifone.com/support/) for that kind of assistance. It'd be very disappointing if a hardware POS solution would allow anyone to customize whatever they want inside of it.

Comment: I mean customize the display. I saw the same one in a SubWay that was customized with their logo and name on it. I am wondering how to do it too

Comment: Customizing POS terminals is not possible. You can't do it yourself. Consult Verifon for support.

Comment: I don't want to customize the terminal, just the credit card machine display

Comment: I guess I will have to contact them to do it if I can't do it myself